# ¿Cómo acceder a un Entry que está dentro de un Widget?

Tags: c#, gtk, mono

Creé el `Widget` que pueden observar a continuación:

[image: Widget de ejemplo]

No consigo la manera de acceder a los `Entrys` (Formularios) que están en él. Necesito extraer el texto que contengan para luego pasarlos a una base de datos.

Para aclarar, esto está programado en MonoDevelop C#, Gtk# 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás utilizando el editor de Gtk# incluido en MonoDevelop.

Debes marcar el campo, y, en el *pad* de propiedades (*properties*), buscar *nombre* (*name*), y cambiar el genérico tipo *entry1* por un nombre que sea significativo. En este ejemplo, yo cambiaría los tres campos, de arriba a abajo, con *edCodigo*, *edDesc* y *edPrecio*.

Una vez hecho esto, solo tienes que utilizar dichos campos directamente desde el código de tu ventana.